# Nginx Location Directive - File gets downloaded

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I currently have setup an Nginx location block that matches a uri if and only if it starts and ends with `/auth/test.php`.  The only match would be `http://host/auth/test.php`.

```
location  ~ ^/auth/test\.php$ {

        # Use try files or the if statement below. try_files is preferred
        # If the original URI ($uri) does not resolve into an existing file or directory, a 404 error is returned
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; #

        fastcgi_param USERNAME $arg_username;
        fastcgi_param PASSWORD $arg_password;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

My understanding is that query parameters don't play a role when Nginx tries to match a location block.  My script, `test.php`, is processed when uri is of the form `http://host/auth/test.php?username=blah&password=blah`. However, if I try a uri without the query parameters (`http://host/auth/test.php`) the script `test.php` gets downloaded by whomever requested it which isn't ideal.  Is there a way in having Nginx not process this type of uri request? I thought the `try_files` directive would take care of this case but apparently not.  Thanks.

Comment: Try `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)($|/.*);` instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still did not work.  When I accesshttp://host/auth/test.php the browser immediately downloads test.php instead of processing the php script.

Comment: @IvanShatsky It was a browser cache issue.  I believe your regular expression would have worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your regular expression is an exact match for a URI string.
So use NGINX's exact (non-regular) matching instead. This will also take
care of ensuring highest priority:

```
location = /auth/test.php {
```

Next, you don't seem to be requiring the URLs of type `/auth/test.php/foo` for forwarding to different PHP files. So get rid of `fastcgi_split_path_info` completely.

The actual `/auth/test.php` script is the one handling the request. So simply put its name in fastcgi directives:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/auth/test.php;
```

Lastly, the `try_files $uri =404;` is irrelevant and may cause more trouble. You already know the file is there, you don't need additional `stat` system calls to check for its existence.

So the complete snippet could be:

```
location = /auth/test.php {
    fastcgi_param USERNAME $arg_username;
    fastcgi_param PASSWORD $arg_password;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/auth/test.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use "=" if you want an exact match for the URI string.

```
location = /auth/test.php {
```

And for the .php to process, the `location` must be something like this:

```
location /auth/test.php {
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
   include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Those two lines allow PHP to be processed regardless of the version of PHP.